# Update ngrx selector inside ngOnChanges

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a parent component `(B)` that is getting data from it's parent input `(A)`
`(C)` have is `(B)` child component.

Inside `(B)` I'm having a selector that gets data from the store.

```
export class BComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() branchId;

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.selectedDataByBranch$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(selectBranchDirections, { branchId: this.branchId, dir: this.selectedDirection })
    );
    this.selectedDataByBranch$.subscribe(selectedDataByBranch => {
      this.trainsDatasets = this.getDatasets(selectedDataByBranch);
      this.lineChart.data.datasets = this.trainsDatasets ? this.trainsDatasets : [];
      this.lineChart.update();
    });
  directionChanged(event) {
    this.selectedDirection = event;
    this.selectedDataByBranch$ = this.store.pipe(
    select(selectBranchDirections, { branchId: this.branchId, dir: this.selectedDirection })
   );
  }
}
```

`directionChanged` is the Output event that I get from `(C)`

The issue this that `selectedDataByBranch` subscription is not getting the new data update triggered inside `selectedDataByBranch$`

I have also tried this way

```
directionChanged(event) {
   this.selectedDirection = event;

  select(selectBranchDirections, { branchId: this.branchId, dir: this.selectedDirection });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i could suggest is. Turn your parameters into a `Subject` then merge with the store selection, in your `directionChanged(event)` method provide value to subject.

So your final code will be something like this:

```
export class BComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() branchId;
    criterias$= new Subject<{branchId:number,dir:number}>;
    ngOnChanges() {
      this.selectedDataByBranch$ = this.criterias$.pipe(mergeMap(criteria=> this.store.pipe(
      select(selectBranchDirections, { branchId: criteria.branchId, dir: this.searchDirection})
    )));    

    this.selectedDataByBranch$.subscribe(selectedDataByBranch => {
      this.trainsDatasets = this.getDatasets(selectedDataByBranch);
      this.lineChart.data.datasets = this.trainsDatasets ? this.trainsDatasets : [];
      this.lineChart.update();
    });
    this.criterias$.next({branchId:this.branchId,dir:this.sortDirection}); // init first call
   }    
  directionChanged(event) {
    this.selectedDirection = event;
    this.criterias$.next({ branchId: criteria.branchId, dir: this.searchDirection}});
   );
  }
}
```

This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yqpu2d) tries to materialize what i say.